# ASP.Net MVC Custom Route to fix URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I created an IOS app where a user can send invites out to people but I messed up the URL and I want to fix it with a custom route because submitting a fix will take a few days. I forgot the controller name in the URL. The URL is like the following

http://example.com/invite/R32f8f8s9f-a889f898

I need it to go to Home/invite/R32f8f8s9f-a889f898

I've tried creating a custom route but I haven't been successful.  Is there a way to do it with routing?

Comment: You probably have your default route set as 'Home'. Change that to something else and the 2nd link should function as you'd like

Comment: The 2nd link is the way I want the first link to behave.  I can't edit the 1st link right now because it is coming from an iOS app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a strict route without specifying a controller and placeholders and direct it your action method

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Invite",
            url: "invite/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Invite", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Don't forget to put it before your default route.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had to create a custom route in a while.